# How to add tooltips for each Item in Combo Box of MFC Dialog

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc

Well, this question may look like a duplicate but since I could not find this question for the platform I am working on, that is why I do not consider it a duplicate question.

Basically I am working on a search module in an **`MFC Application`** and I am using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/489189/Group-Combo-Box) project as a reference, the class is derived from [CComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12h9x0ch.aspx). Everything works fine but I also need to add `tooltip` for each item of the combo box. I found some articles i.e. [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/187753/Extended-CComboBox) one is a good article but I do not have any idea how to merge it with the one that I am using.
Someone please guide me **how to add a tooltip for each item of the CCombo Box?**

Thanks in advance.